# C# search text file, return all lines containing a word

Tags: c#, winforms, full-text-search

I need help with a program i'm building at my internship.
The idea is to check how frequent a user logs in on any PC.
When a user logs in, that information is logged in a text file, like this format.

```
01-01-2011 16:47:10-002481C218B0-WS3092-Chsbe (XP-D790PRO1)
```

Now i need to search the text file and (for example) search the text file for all login dates for the user Chsbe.

My code so far:

```
private void btnZoek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int counter = 0; string line;  
            // Read the file and display it line by line. 
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\log.txt"); 
            while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {     if ( line.Contains(txtZoek.Text) )     
            {
                txtResult.Text = line.ToString();                
            }     

            }  
            file.Close(); 
        }
```

My question is, How do i return all the strings in the log containing the searchterm to txtResult?

Comment: Is it possbile to get the source as xml ? 
Otherwise as mentioned before look at regex.
If searches become more complex have a look at some kind of fulltext search components

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are already doing a good work. The only error is in the writing of the last line read into the textbox overwriting the previous one.
You need to use a StringBuilder and a `using` statement around your disposable Stream like this:

```
private void btnZoek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)         
{             
    int counter = 0; string line;               
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Read the file and display it line by line.              
    using(System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\log.txt"))
    {
       while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)             
       {     
         if ( line.Contains(txtZoek.Text) )                  
         {          
              // This append the text and a newline into the StringBuilder buffer       
              sb.AppendLine(line.ToString());
         }                   
      }               
   }
   txtResult.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

of course, your txtResult should have the property MultiLine set to true, otherwise you will be unable to see the output.
Keep in mind that `using` is the better way to handle this kind of situations because it automatically handles also unexpected file exceptions taking care to correctly close your Stream

Comment: Yes! this is it! Thanks for the fast help, Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Use richtextbox or use multiline property
for example

```
private void btnZoek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0; string line;  
        // Read the file and display it line by line. 
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\log.txt"); 
        while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {     if ( line.Contains(txtZoek.Text) )     
        {
            richtextbox1.Text += "\n" + line.ToString();
            txtresult.Text += "\n" + line.ToString();
        }     

        }  
        file.Close(); 
    }
```

Comment: Btw. I don't think that this will be much of help for the treadstarter. You should at least actually call the class-name. Link to the MSDN or show the initalisation.. ...that would explain more and than there would also be the "why" use a richtextbox.

Comment: Anyway, don't understand, how RichTextBox relate to OP question. All he need, according to his question, is multiline textbox and accumulate text, not replace.

Comment: If you use textbox (i think that txtresult is textbox) you should add multiline property. Richtextbox use this property on default, i just want show easy example how to get needed result.

Comment: richtextbox1.Text += "\n" + line.ToString();  this is answer

Comment: So can you pls make this answer correct? and thank you for upvote

Answer (score 0):

Define an List

List yourList = new List();

Replace the Line
txtResult.Text = line.ToString();
by
yourList.Add(line);

in the List "yourList" you got all Lines containing the User

Comment: I tried this but it won't make a list at all.. can you clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below might help get you started with regex:

```
string pattern = "Chsbe"; 
Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
MatchCollection mc = rx.Matches(inputText); 

foreach (Match m in mc) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnZoek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 0; string line;  
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    // Read the file and display it line by line. 
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\log.txt"); 
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(txtZoek.Text))     
        {
            str.Append(line.ToString());                
        }     
    }  
    file.Close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work.

```
    private void btnZoek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0; string line;  
        // Read the file and display it line by line. 
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\log.txt"); 
        while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {     if ( line.Contains(txtZoek.Text) )     
        {
            txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text + Environment.Newline + line.ToString();                
        }     

        }  
        file.Close(); 
    }
```

This would be my version:

```
    private void btnZoek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string line;
            List<String> LinesFound = new List<string>();

            // Read the file and display it line by line. 
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\log.txt");

            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(txtZoek.Text))
                {
                    LinesFound.Add(line);
                }

            }
            file.Close();

            foreach (string Line in LinesFound)
            {
                txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text + Line + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in btnZoek_Click");
        }
    }
```

If the list is really long I would use a StringBuilder to create a result string as a performance speedup.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this Line ->

```
txtResult.Text = line.ToString();
```

to:

```
txtResult.Text += line.ToString();
```